# Include Site.com page in div or iframe

Tags: site.com, website-integration, iframe

I don't know if this is more of a html problem, anyway, I am trying to embed a site.com page into a div in an html page.

The vf page can be seen in my browser so it should not be a visibility problem.
I've tried with an iframe with this tag:

```
<iframe id="theFrame" src="http://test.force.com/site/TestPageSite" style="width:100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

And also with a div:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://dev-org.cs17.force.com/survey/TestPageSite" style="width:100%; height:100%">
<p>backup content</p>
```

But I can't see anything. Do you believe this is a Site.com page problem? The page is actually very simple - it was just a test:

```
<apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="This is {0} text with {1}.">
       <apex:param value="my"/>
       <apex:param value="arguments"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Is this Site.com or a Force.com Site? Based on your code including Apex (not available in Site.com pages) I think it is a Force.com Site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the X-Frame-Options HTTP header.

On the Force.com Site itself, can you enable 'Allow in Frames'?

Comment: Yes, by setting the Clickjack Protection Level to 'Allow framing by the same origin only (no protection)' it works. Thanks!